# What is causing my animation to flicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, styles

I'm doing a simple animation that works as expected until i put a border around my grid.  As soon as i do this then the animation flickers when i mouse click the frame.  I'm trying to achieve a menu that "slides" into view.  I have included my code below. Its almost like somehow my mouse click is causing an infinite animation loop.

```
<Border  BorderBrush="YellowGreen" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="10" Background="Black">
        <Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="DragWindow">
            <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Frame" x:Key="GrowingFrameStyle">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#505050"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="LightGray" />
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="SteelBlue" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="20" To="50" Duration="0:0:.3" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="#505050" />
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Black" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="50" To="20" Duration="0:0:.3" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Black"/>
            <Frame Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="SlateBlue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource GrowingFrameStyle}"/>        
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Only method in the code behind

```
private void DragWindow(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  DragMove();
}
```

Comment: We probably need to see the DragWindow method

Comment: I reproduced the problem.  A click is an IsMouseOver start over with a border but not without.  I don't know why.  If you click in the top 20 the storyboard just runs once.  If you click in the bottom 20-50 you get a loop. I know not an answer and they is why I posted as a comment.

Comment: I think the answer is some where in event bubbling.  If you turn IsHitVisable=false on the Border then nothing happens.  I know not an answer but it indicate that border is in the even sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by clicking on an expanded area of the `Frame`.

The `MouseUp` event seems to be firing a `MouseLeave`/`MouseEnter` event. The `MouseLeave` is trigging the animation to shrink the frame, which queues a Shrink storyboard event, and the `MouseEnter` is queuing the animation to expand the frame, which queues an Expand storyboard event. By shrinking/expanding the frame, the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` get fired again and the animations both get run again. These two keep firing endlessly until you move the mouse out of the magical area that is only occupied when the Frame is expanded.

You can view the delay in slow-motion by adding `BeginTime="00:00:02"` to your Storyboards to add a 2-second delay, and you can verify the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events by attaching a method which writes a line to output in the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events of the Frame.

As for fixing it, I'm not sure the best way to do that. Perhaps try using the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events to trigger the events manually after a 1-second delay providing the event should still process.

For example, if the `MouseUp` event triggers `MouseLeave` and `MouseEnter` events, then the `MouseLeave` should queue the collapse animation, but delay a second and check if the Mouse is actually over the object a second later. If not, cancel the collapse event. This would cause the `MouseLeave` event not to fire its animation, which means it won't queue animations endlessly until the mouse is moved off the expanded Frame's area.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent animation flickering, you can remove `From="20"` in the EnterAction, and remove `To="20"` in the ExitAction.

The animations will use "20" anyway since that is already the base value, unless that value is different because of an animation already in progress, so it effectively just reverses the animation instead of flickering (resetting to 20 every single time the animation is triggered).